# Alternate between different views using Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am preparing an iPad app using, obviously, Objetive-C and wich tries to deploy Data Base stored content inside a view.
Now comes the problem, it will be a huge amount of records to be shown, each of them deployed inside some kind of "container" inside the view so that I was considering to make a page browser and in every page I go to change the view I apply.
Take for example, I show the first 5 items using example1.xib, for the next 5 example2.xip and so til getting to the page 10 and starting again with example1.xib.
My question is how this can be achieved? Maybe storing diferent view class based objects inside an array and alternating them or so...
Any help or hint would be greatly apreciated.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I would subclass [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [UITableViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) depending on what type of records you plan on using.

---

I would recommend checking all the [Apple's Examples](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code), and most of the available online tutorial

Here are some, may be old though...

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/tabbarcontroller-with-navigationcontroller-and-tableview-in-iphone/

http://www.aboveground.com/tutorials/adding-a-uitableview-to-a-custom-uiview

http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/08/iphone-programming-tutorial-populating-uitableview-with-an-nsarray/

http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=150

http://www.ioschef.com/2011/03/un-aperitivo-de-uitableview-y-uitableviewcontroller/  in spanish..

http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-part-1-uitableview-using-nsarray/    with videotutorial

Comment: Hi, maybe it's my newbie status with Objective-C ^_^ but what do you mean exactly with sublassing UIViewController?

Answer (score 0):

Always assume others have made similar apps before you. Perhaps not exactly the same ones as you, but doing similar things that you can learn from. The iPod and Spotify apps navigate large amounts of data using indexed, searchable TableViews. Go hunting on App Store for apps that have the same kind of functionality as yours, and test them out and grab what's good and discard what's bad about them.

My advice is to get hold of a nested tables example using the built in SQLite, and go from there. I've no idea what your database looks like, but with a bit of luck you could adapt example code and just open (a converted) SQL database.

Most users by now are used to the drill down paradigm rather than the paginated paradigm, so it's worth checking out the Drill Down example that comes with XCode even if it's not for databases (at least I don't think it is, I learned from a book, like Manuel.)

Comment: Thanks! I gonna try out some existing apps and look at the Drill Down example, cheers!